# SAS: Determine programmatically what machine SAS is running on

Tags: sas, environment

I am trying to write a macro, but it accesses a path variable

- on Windows, it may be C:\Temp
- On Unix, it may be /tmp

How can I figure out programmatically  what type of machine my SAS is running on so I can assign to appropriate value to path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%put _automatic_;` is the first place you should go when looking for things like this - this shows all of the automatically defined macro variables, many of which define your working environment.

In this case, `&SYSSCPL.` gives the operating system (in my case `X64_7PRO` for windows 7 64 bit).  There is also `&SYSHOSTNAME` which is the computer's "name" (defined differently on various OSs).